# Custom Speech: "normalized text is empty"

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I uploaded a wav and text file to the custom speech portal. I got the following error: “Error: normalized text is empty.”
The text file is UTF-8 BOM, and is similar in format to a file that did work. 
How I can trouble-shoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several reasons for a normalized text to be empty, e.g. if there are words of Latin and non-Latin characters in a sentence (depending on the locale). Also, words that are repeated multiple times in a row may cause this. Can you share which locale you're using to import the data? If you could share the text we can find the reason. Otherwise you could try to reduce the input text (no need to cut the audio for this) to find out what causes the normalization to discard the sentence.

Comment: It's 58 kB. It was converted to ASCII, and back to UTF-8. Can extra spaces or hyphens be a problem?

Comment: Is this happening during a conversion process with azure cognitive services? Could I create a similar error if I ran a c# program that normalizes the text of the file and checks the length?

Comment: Which (System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm) does custom speech use?

Comment: I ran it through Normalize and got these results:
Length of regular string = 59082
Length of normalized string FormC = 59082
Length of normalized string FormD = 59082

Length of normalized string FormKC = 59082

Length of normalized string FormKD = 59082

Length of normalized string = 59082

Comment: Update: I removed "--" from the file, and it loaded successfully.